# Rails - How to link underscore template from html file to coffescript file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I have two files:
**UPDATE:**
I updated files with whole code, so maybe someone could see why template is not being used. Maybe I'm missing something.
script.js.coffee
which has this view (using Backbone.js):

```
 window.Book = Backbone.Model.extend(url: ->
    (if @id then "/books/" + @id else "/books")
  )

  Router = Backbone.Router.extend(routes:
    "": "home"
    new: "editBook"
    "edit/:id": "editBook"
  )


  Books = Backbone.Collection.extend(model: Book)
  books = new Books()
  books.url = "books.json"



  BooksView = Backbone.View.extend(
    el: ".books"
    render: ->
      books = new Books()
      books.fetch success: =>
        template = _.template($("#book-list-template").html(),
          books: books.models
        )
        @$el.html template
        console.log template
  )
```

And another file index.html.erb

having this template:

```
<div id="main">
<h1>Books list</h1>
<div class="books"></div>
 <script type="text/template" id="book-list-template">
    <a href="#new" class="btn btn-primary">New Book</a>
    <table class="table striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Author</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <%% _.(books).each(function(book) { %>
          <tr>
            <td><%%= book.title  %></td>
            <td><%%= book.author  %></td>
            <td><%%= book.year  %></td>
            <td><a href="#/edit/<%%= book.id %>" class="btn">Edit</a></td>
          </tr>
        <%% }); %>
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </script>  

</div>
```

But it does not show anything (does not give any errors either).For me it looks like coffee file can not see where is template? Is there a way to simply show it where it is? Or am I missing something?

P.S. I'm using rails 4

Answer (score 0):

[`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) doesn't set any specific context for the `success` callback so `@` is probably `window` when you try to `$(@el).html(template)`. [Fat-arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) that callback and you should have better results:

```
books.fetch success: =>
  template = _.template($("#book-list-template").html(),
    books: books.models
  )
  @$el.html template
```

You can also use the cached version of `$(@el)` version of that is in [`@$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) too.

---

And while I'm here, you usually use [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) to serialize your collection for your template:

```
template = _.template($("#book-list-template").html(), books.toJSON())
```

and then in your template:

```
<%% _(books).each(function(book) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><%%= book.title  %></td>
     <td><%%= book.author %></td>
     <td><%%= book.year   %></td>
     <td><a href="#/edit/<%%= book.id %>" class="btn">Edit</a></td>
   </tr>
 <%% }); %>
```

This approach helps you avoid accidentally modifying your real data inside your template.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Got error `SyntaxError: unexpected @` changing, to `$(el).html template` solved error. But still can't see my form displayed.. If I tried this view instead:

`  BooksView = Backbone.View.extend(
    el: ".books"
    addOne: (model) ->
      view = new BookView(model: model)
      $(view.el).append
      $("ul.books").append view.render()
  )`

Then it outputs list, but then I can't use template..

Comment: Are you sure you tried `@$el` rather than `$@el`? `@$el` is fine, `$@el` would give you an "unexpected @" error.

Comment: Yes you were right, I used `$@el`. Now changed it, but still no output.

Comment: Do you have a `.books` in the DOM when instantiate your view?

Comment: I don't see anything that creates and renders your `BooksView`. There should be a `v = new BooksView; v.render()` somewhere.

Comment: yes I was missing that. I added it, but I'm getting this error now:
`Error initially occurred at line 1206, column 6 in <anonymous function: _.template>(text, data, settings) in http://localhost:3000/assets/underscore.js?body=1:
    render = new Function(settings.variable || 'obj', '_', source);`
Don't see where _.template is missing paranthesis or something?

Comment: Strange. Other browser shows this error:
`Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'text' to object`

Comment: I still don't see where the view is being instantiated. You probably have an order problem somewhere in the code I can't see. You probably need a `$ ->` wrapper somewhere.

Comment: I instantiated view after defining view.